# explain this shell script to me please

Tags: shell

I am confused with this make.sh file. I read previous posts about shell scripts structure but I could not find out about this file. what is the function of this file? ....

Can anyone explain it step by step?

```
#!/bin/sh

    rm out/*
    example_number=0

    for name in `ls in`
    do


     out=`cat in/$name | grep ".o " | tr -s \  | cut -d\  -f2`
     inp=`cat in/$name | grep ".i " | tr -s \  | cut -d\  -f2`

     echo -n "${name} (i=${inp}, o=${out}) "

     if [ $inp -le 12 ]
     then


     cat in/$name \
     | sed '/.i/d' \
     | sed '/.o/d' \
     | sed '/.p/d' \
     | sed '/.e/d' \
     | sed 's/|/ /g' \
     | tr -s \  \
     | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' \
     > out/${name}.in

      tst=`cat out/${name}.in | cut -d\  -f2  | grep - -c`

      if [ $tst -ne 0 ]
      then
        echo "remove file"
        rm out/${name}.in
      else
        echo processing...
        ./unix2dos.exe -q out/${name}.in
        example_number=`expr $example_number + 1`
      fi

     else
      echo " skip"

     fi
    done



     for name in `grep 2 -l out/*`
     do
       echo Remove $name
       rm $name
        example_number=`expr $example_number - 1`
     done

    echo Number of examples is $example_number

    # bad files
    # apla ( 222? )
    # tms
    # mainpa...
```

Comment: You need to read and study about unix shell programming. An answer is beyond the scope or purpose of SO.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a Makefile, but a shell script. You can see this from the file extension `.sh` and from the header

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Which is the instruction to use the shell to execute this file.

Comment: @sasha that would be a little much. Try to read a little about shell scripting and then ask a more specific question.